# IIS 7 virtual directory 404 error

Tags: iis-7.5

I have set up a virtual directory called application under the default website. Inside this, i have a web applcation running. When i browse 80 from IIS and log into the homepage is fine, but then when i click onto go to another menu (subdirectory) i keep getting 404. I have created the necessary virtual directories and checked permissions on the folder and app pool. the iis log shows the following

```
2012-09-04 09:54:08 ::1 GET /application/TeamCentral/Common/images/20/h_row.jpg - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 64
2012-09-04 09:54:08 ::1 GET /application/TeamCentral/Images/risk_32x32.png - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 26
2012-09-04 09:54:08 ::1 GET /application/TeamCentral/Survey/Images/survey_32x32.png - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 28
2012-09-04 09:54:08 ::1 GET /application/TeamCentral/common/images/20/logout.gif - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 35
2012-09-04 09:54:08 ::1 GET /application/TeamCentral/favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 200 0 0 17
2012-09-04 09:54:08 ::1 GET /application/images/arrowdown.gif - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 404 0 2 2
*****2012-09-04 09:54:15 ::1 GET /TeamCentral/Auditors/HomePage.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/21.0.1180.83+Safari/537.1 404 0 0 2141*****
```

Its the last line thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that either the file is not able to be browsed or more likely is that the ASP.NET filter is not enabled for this specific subdirectory.  Not really sure why that would happen but it almost sounds like your virtual directory settings may be a bit hosed.  Assuming you can browse a sample text or html file in that folder my guess is your ASP.NET settings are hosed.